# Python Ctype title different language

Tags: python

Why does the title I make turn to Chinese?

```
import ctypes
Title = "Test"
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(Title)
```

Why is it chinese when i execute the code

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`SetConsoleTitleW` expects a unicode string. If you're using 2.7 or below, `"Test"` is not a unicode string. Try:

```
import ctypes
Title = u"Test"
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(Title)
```

Alternatively, use `SetConsoleTitleA`, which accepts ANSI bytes.

```
import ctypes
Title = "Test"
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(Title)
```

Comment: Do you know how I could use this over a socket server?

Comment: That's rather outside the scope of this question, I think. Play around with it for a while and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Well I can only ask 1 question a week and I did it soooo I need to know here

Comment: That's strange. If your account is in good standing, you should be able to ask as many questions as you like.

Comment: Yeah it says I need to wait 7 days